# actionbar menu item onclick?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I have an action bar that puts everything in a menu in the top right, which the user clicks and the menu options open up.

I inflate the action bar menu with this on each activity I use it:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);

        return true;
    }
```

And my xml for main2.xml is:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_searchHome"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Seach"/>



</menu>
```

My question is do I put an onclick in the item in the xml and if so where do I put the onclick method it calls? Do I need to put it in every activity I launch this action bar in?

Comment: I think you might be looking for [onOptionsItemSelected](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem))

Comment: Check my comment under Eghdk reply, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396870/actionbar-menu-item-onclick#comment-25260264

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you add an onClick attribute on your menu item like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_searchHome"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:onClick="doThis"
        android:title="Seach"/>



</menu>
```

Then in your activity:

```
public void doThis(MenuItem item){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**Note:**

ActionBarSherlock is **deprecated**. Unless you are developing an app for Android 4.0 or older, please don't use it. But if you are using the library, you will have to import

`import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;`

*and not*

`import com.android.view.MenuItem;`

In addition, you could do something like this: [ActionBar Sherlock Menu Item OnClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472443/actionbar-sherlock-menu-item-onclick)

which @adneal mentions.

Comment: No this is not the way to do this, `AcitonBars` have their own method to deal with clicks. Look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu

Comment: Both ways work. Also, I mentioned the method you just listed at the end of my answer.

Comment: Yes, technically, both can work, but one way is the the right way and the other is a terrible terrible way. it creates chaos and incoherence in the code. Please for the love of God, never use this method for Menu items.

Comment: @LuckyMe why? this is typical command binding. .NET developers do it all the time :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    add_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onCreateDialog(getTaskId());
        }
    });
}


<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/add_text_id" android:title="Add"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_btn"
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```