# PopupWindow or PopupMenu? Or something else?

Tags: android, popupwindow, popupmenu

I'm trying to create very similar layout like Google Play Books. I need to create an PopupMenu or PopupWindow, which will be displayed at the same position like in the picture below.

[image: PopupWindow (or PopupMenu)]

I am not sure, if it is `PopupMenu` or `PopupWindow` or something else. This "window" is displayed when I click on the item from menu.

In case, that I change an orientation to landscape mode, in `ActionBar` is a new icon, which displays this "window". The picture below shows this situation:

[image: PopupWindow (or PopupMenu) in landscape]

I have two questions:

1. Is this a `PopupMenu`, `PopupWindow` or something else?
2. How can I determine the position of this "window" in case, that it is the `PopupWindow` and I need to show it?

Comment: I always preferred to use a PopupWindow, you can fully customize it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And can you tell me, please, how can I determine the position of PopupWindow? In the pictures, the PopupWindow is always in the different position. It depends on orientation of screen.

Comment: http://codingaffairs.blogspot.com/2017/05/popupwindow-android-using-cardview.html

Answer (score 4):

You have to create an `OnClickListener` like this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int[] location = new int[2];
        v.getLocationOnScreen(location);

        // Initialize the Point with x, and y positions
        Point point = new Point();
        point.x = location[0];
        point.y = location[1];

        popupWindow(v, point);

    }

});
```

The method for `popupWindow(View view, Point point)`:

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapterTypeSelection;

private void popupWindow(View v, Point p) {
    // int popupwindowWidth =
    // UnitConverterClass.convertDpToPx(180,getActivity());
    int popupwindowHeight = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(
        R.layout.dashboard_profile_popup_window, null);

    // Creating the PopupWindow
    final PopupWindow pwindow = new PopupWindow(getActivity());
    pwindow.setContentView(layout);
    // pwindow.showAsDropDown(v);
    // pwindow.setWidth(popupwindowWidth);
    pwindow.setHeight(popupwindowHeight);
    pwindow.setFocusable(true);

    String[] types = {"hello", "hi"};

    adapterTypeSelection = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        R.layout.<your layout for the popupwindow>,
        R.id.textView, types);

    ListView listview = (ListView) pwindow.getContentView().findViewById(
        R.id.listview_popwindow);

    listview.setAdapter(adapterTypeSelection);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

            TextView temp = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(position)
                .findViewById(R.id.textView);

            if (temp.getText()
                .toString()
                .equals("hello"))) {
                    //hello
            } else {
                //hi
            }

            pwindow.dismiss();
        }
    });

    pwindow.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            //TODO dismiss settings
        }

    });

    pwindow.setWidth(<width>);
    pwindow.setBackgroundDrawable(<resource for background>);

    // int OFFSET_X = UnitConverterClass.convertDpToPx(180, getActivity());
    // int OFFSET_Y = UnitConverterClass.convertDpToPx(30, getActivity());
    // pwindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 
    //                                p.x + OFFSET_X, p.y + OFFSET_Y);
    pwindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x, p.y);
}
```

Hope this helps to make a `PopupWindow` in the position you want to show it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I know that I have to use PopupWindow. But still I cannot make the PopupWindow in the position I want, because in your code, the PopupWindow is displayed when click on the button. I need to show it if I click on the item from menu.

Comment: You have to set the OnClickListener for the items.

Comment: But `MenuItem` does not have `OnClickListener`, right?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17396896/3465623 . Then, on the method you just put what I have on my `OnClickListener`.

Comment: http://codingaffairs.blogspot.com/2017/05/popupwindow-android-using-cardview.html