# Problems with toolbar menu items and activities

Tags: java, android, xml

I've create an menu (my toolbar) and an item inside of it (Settings)

menu.xml code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.sergio.testecalc.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:title="@string/config"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

I want to link the onClick with Settings_Activity.java, then I put this on Main_Activity.java:

```
public void sendMessage(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

But Android Studio shows me that:

Method sendMessage in MainActivity has incorrect signature

[image]

Why? Whats wrong with my code? Sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: You need to override `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your issue, change `View` to `MenuItem` like so:

```
public void sendMessage(MenuItem mItem)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396870/actionbar-menu-item-onclick) for more details.

Note that it's more common to use `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479992/handling-a-menu-item-click-event-android) for details.