# Android crash on Selecting ABS Item

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

For whatever reason, my ActionBar crashes when I click on one of its buttons. Here's the code for the optionsSelectMenu:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{   
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.refresh_button_actionbar:
        if (this.frag instanceof DashboardFragment)
            dashboardFrag.refresh();
        break;
    default: 
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And here is the logcat:

```
07-30 19:17:52.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1358): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 19:17:52.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1358): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 19:17:52.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.toString(MenuItemImpl.java:496)
07-30 19:17:52.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:202)
07-30 19:17:52.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:201)
07-30 19:17:52.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:980)
07-30 19:17:52.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
07-30 19:17:52.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
07-30 19:17:52.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
07-30 19:17:52.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:547)
07-30 19:17:52.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:115)
07-30 19:17:52.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
07-30 19:17:52.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
07-30 19:17:52.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-30 19:17:52.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-30 19:17:52.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-30 19:17:52.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-30 19:17:52.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 19:17:52.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-30 19:17:52.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-30 19:17:52.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-30 19:17:52.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong? I'm thinking it has to do with the fragment comparison. Also, to note, when I just set the code to "return true" (as in it will do nothing but return true), it will re-start the activity. Is this intended behavior? If so, how can I get around it?

Here are my imports:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

import com.actifio.android.R;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Android's Menu and MenuInflater, but should be using the classes that come with ActionBarSherlock. Check if this is your import for them:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
```

Check the answer given in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278952/adding-a-button-to-the-actionbar-with-actionbarsherlock) for a detailed explanation.Your problem should be solved. Next time make sure if this type of question is asked already.

**EDIT:**

I came up with a tweak(not very clean but works) to solve your problem. Hope you have the actionbarsharlock project in your workspace. Go to the package `com.actionbarsharlock.app` then locate the file `SharlockFragmentActivity.java`,open it up and go to line 201 (CMD/CTRL+L then enter the line number) now comment out the following lines:

```
try
        {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "[onMenuItemSelected] featureId: " + featureId + ", item: " + item);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"Exception");
        }
```

Your problem should be fixed.

Comment: The thing is, the imports I'm using are from Action Bar Sherlock. They match those exactly.

Comment: I don't get this then. Take a look at the log cat output.`java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 19:17:52.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.toString(MenuItemImpl.java:496)` If you have used sharlock imports then the error should be from `com.actionbarsharlock.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl` class. Please recheck your code. I am afraid you have imported both but using the android one.

Comment: Added my imports to the main thread. Those are the only ones I'm using :/ Not using any of the default Android ones.
I'm instantiating the Action Bar with getSupportActionBar(), and the inflater with getSupportMenuInflater().